# VB.Net Open New Form Instance as Separate Process

Tags: vb.net, pid, toolstripmenu

I am trying to launch a separate instance of my application with a new process ID. Is there any way to do this? The following code will show a separate form, but it shares the process ID of the original form:

```
Private Sub NewToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim SecondForm As New MyForm()
    SecondForm.Show()
End Sub
```

I basically want to replicate the same behavior as opening the application when a user selects the New option from the tool strip menu.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, and accept it as soon as you can, to avoid clutter on Stackoverflow. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Neolisk! I'm new to posting on SO, and I didn't know about these features.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for what I was trying to do.

```
Private Sub NewToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click        
    Dim ExePath As String = Application.ExecutablePath
    Process.Start(ExePath)
End Sub
```